# How to prevent Excel documents (.xlsx) opening in Excel Services on a mobile device

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, mobile

I have a customer that wants to use the BB(Blackberry) mobile device to open all excel documents (both .xls and .xlsx) using the client application on the device and not excel services. Is this possible?

It looks like for documents that have a file extension of .xls, the document downloads to the client and opens in the client's default application, but when the file has an extension of .xlsx it opens in Excel Services and the user experience is pretty bad, we're using an older version of BB, real old!!!.

I'm aware of the Browser File Handler setting that's set on the web application level and the library and list level, but neither options works for more. It appears in the mobile view is where I can reproduce the customer's issue.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site collection and then site collections features

```
_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site
```

and Activate "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default"

This should fix the issue, it just did on my test environment.